# How to call controller from handler?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have Handler.php (`app/Exceptions/Handler.php`)

I want to call the controller method from render method of `Handler.php`.

Here is the render method and what I have tried,

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{   
    $common_vars                    = app()->call(\App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class."@".getMenusAndConfigs('users'));
    if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
        switch ($e->getStatusCode()) {

            // not authorized
            case '403':
                return \Response::view('errors.403', array(), 403);
                break;

            // not found
            case '404':
                return \Response::view('errors.404', $common_vars, 404);
                break;

            // internal error
            case '500':
                return \Response::view('errors.500', array(), 500);
                break;

            default:
                return $this->renderHttpException($e);
                break;
        }
    } else {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
    // return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

I can get `$common_vars` by calling test controller in other controllers, but I want this in Handler.php

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> you can call any method of controller like that. does this help.

```
 /** @var TestController $testController */
     $testController = app(\App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class);
     $commonVars = $testController->getMenusAndConfigs('users');
```

Comment: Its work for me, its call at anywhere. Jay murlidhar.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wrong call method? Try like this:

```
$common_vars = app()->call(
    [app(\App\Http\Controllers\TestController::class), 'getMenusAndConfigs'], 
    ['YOUR_ARG_NAME' => 'users'] 
);
```

Replace YOUR_ARG_NAME with `getMenusAndConfigs` argument name.

**Note:** Best practice for cases like this is using `View Composers` - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers

Comment: You do not show the implementation of getMenusAndConfigs. It's not work, if getMenusAndConfigs is not static. If it not static, you must pass object to `app->call`.

Comment: It is working method which is used to almost all other controllers. I called my way and your way, still it doesn't work. Method is not static. Its working in @Shailesh's way

Answer (score 1):

It is Not at all Good Idea to Call or use the Controller methods in Another Controllers Other than extending parent Controller Methods.,

The purpose of a single Controller is for a Single Functionality, All Reusable Logic Should be Moved to Repositories. The controller should only accept the request perform logic by using repositories and respond back to the request.

In your case

Add a `Repositories` folder inside `app` folder we are adding inside `app` folder because all `classes` inside `app` folder will be auto loaded while `bootstrapping`. inside the Repositories folder add your repository classes.

in the `Handler` add a Constructor, inject the constructor and create an object for that constructor

```
public function __construct(MenuRepository $menus) {
  $this->menus = $menus;
}
```

and inside your `render` method you can write like

```
$commonVars = $this->menus->getMenusAndConfigs('users');
```

> `getMenusAndConfigs($userType) {}` method should be inside the
>   `MenuRepository`

Hope this Helps

Have a look into this Discussion why we are using Repository Pattern [Repository Pattern in Laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/repository-pattern-in-50?page=1)

Comment: @Rahul_m, use Repository pattern for Reusable components.,it is not a good idea of accessing the controller methods in another controller or in jobs.

Comment: I will remember this in next project. Right now I cant :)

Comment: @rahul_m Sure Thanks